# How can I reuse CSS styles between different components in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, components

**Edit** - Following comments and thinking this through a bit, I have added the options as I see them to the bottom of this question.

**Original Question**
I have an Angular component (down below, html and scss file, nothing really in the component class for brevity).  Lets call it "h5-underliner" and used like:

`<app-h5-underliner>My Title</app-h5-underliner>`

`

```css
h5 {
    margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

h5:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0.1rem;
    height: 0.2rem;
    width: 6rem;
    background: $colour-apg-accent;
}
```

```html
<h5 [class]="colourThemeName">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</h5>
```

`

Now say for example I want an "h2 underliner"

`<app-h2-underliner>My Heading 2 Title</app-h2-underliner>`

Which picks up the apps h2 styling.

How can I aceive this without duplicating all the css (which would end up something like the below:)

`

```css
h2 {
    margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

h2:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0.1rem;
    height: 0.2rem;
    width: 6rem;
    background: $colour-apg-accent;
}
```

`

It's not a huge example, but I dont like the repetition.  I thought about a directive, but the pseudo selector after kills that idea (as far as I am aware).

Note there is a little bit of extra going on as the caller can choose a colour, but that just means more repetition between very similar components (i.e. only the h5 and h2 tags differ).

---

**So options:**

*Option 1* - The mess abouve with `<h2-underliner>Mt Title Text<\h2-underliner>` and `<h5-underliner>Mt Title Text<\h5-underliner>` - bad for several reaons.

*Option 2* - Global style for the css that can be applied to tags as required (.my-underliner) OR we make the decision that all h5 and h2 titles have this style.  On one hand we set typography globally with mat custom typography - but it doesn't seem right to start adding global css for general css.

*Option 3* - A component that follows the same pattern as material form field/content projection: `<app-underliner><h5>My title text</h5></app-underliner>` - in this case we contain the common style to one component and still have the freedom to use it with different headings.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you cannot just use a css class to apply these stylings where you need them?

Comment: @MikkelChristensen I guess I am looking for the best pattern to use - I added this as an option.

Answer (score 3):

Styles follow hierarchical override in angular. So if both of those components that you refer lets call them B, C are children of component A, then you can put those styles on component A.

Then B, C will inherit those styles from parent A

They don't even have to be direct children of A to inherit styles of A.
So in a structure like

```
 A - D - C

 |_ B
```

D, C , B will inherit styles declared in component A

Comment: Hey thanks, but I should clarify. I have the need for some places to add an underline to a H2 tag and in other places a H5.  The underline is practically the same. If it were not in angular, you could just apply a class to both. But that doesn't feel right in Ng (a global style).

Comment: I guess I could have '<app-titler><h5>My title text</h5></app-titler>'. But what CSS can I add to the app titler?

Comment: @kenam you don't do it like that. You have <app-titler></app-titler> and then you go inside the component app-titler and in html file or template you declare <h5>....</h5> and also in styles file whatever you want for H5 or you do it on a parent component and you inherit the style from parent

Comment: That's kind of what I had, but now I'm thinking.  it's a bit like '<mat-form-field>' pattern?  The underliner/titler component will apply the underline to whatever is inside the component tags?   It's late I need to think about this tomorrow!

Comment: I updated the question - I think I have what you are saying, sorry if I misunderstood - please let me know.